# Google API - request for token from Oauth2 returns “invalid_request”

Tags: oauth-2.0

I know this has been asked before, but the suggestions in other posts haven't helped.
I successfully receive an authorization token from google, but when I try to get the access token, I get an invalid_request.

Our first attempt in PHP resulted in that response, when I tried it through my HTTP client, I get the same. Finally, I tried directly with CURL and still got the same results:

```
curl -v -k --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-F 'code=4/U2su0fwiynq4v8J8xD56ohfF0fX6.EhP0brx3cosbuJJVnL49Cc8EFE7ncQI' \
-F 'client_id=012345678901-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345.apps.googleusercontent.com' \
-F 'client_secret=ABC123ABC123ABC123ABC123' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=https://app.myserver.com/googleLogin.php' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

The response I receive is:

```
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
* About to connect() to accounts.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.194.77.84... connected
* Connected to accounts.google.com (173.194.77.84) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using RC4-SHA
* Server certificate:
*      subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=accounts.google.com
*      start date: 2011-07-21 00:00:00 GMT
*      expire date: 2013-07-18 23:59:59 GMT
*      common name: accounts.google.com (matched)
*      issuer: C=ZA; O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd.; CN=Thawte SGC CA
*      SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: accounts.google.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 771
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=----------------------------0d3dc3507a7f
> 
* Done waiting for 100-continue
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Date: Sat, 04 Aug 2012 22:07:07 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Server: GSE
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
* Connection #0 to host accounts.google.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

I'm not url-encoding anything before I send it, but when I do, I get the same result.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try performing the same requests with the OAuth 2.0 Playground and compare them with yours:

https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Thanks Claudio - but I don't see any differences. That app confirms that the params must be url-encoded (as I thought) and everything in the payload I'm sending *is* encoded. The only difference I see is that my client_id is much longer and a different format than Google's and that of many other examples I see out there (Google's: 407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com)

Comment: Got it! In my request for the authorization code, my 'approval_prompt' was set to 'auto' -- google was setting theirs to 'force'. I changed mine to force and it worked.
Thanks for the tip in the right direction!

Comment: That didn't help me, I still have the same error. Invalid Request.

Comment: I'm facing same problem can anyone help me..?